# How get the value of multiple checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I used checkbox in two items now I can get the value of the second group of checkbox.
The first group of checkbox I use:

```
<input name="option" type="checkbox" value="1" id="option1">option 1
<input name="option" type="checkbox" value="2" id="option2">option 2
```

Then

```
<input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="1" id="choice1">choice 1
<input name="choice" type="checkbox" value="2" id="choice2">choice 2
```

How can i get the value of selected checkboxes, in each group it is only allowed to select 1 checkbox.

I just need the javascript function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this following codes to get the value of the checkbox if you are using multiple checkboxes.

$('input[name=option]:checked').val();

Comment: this will only return the value of the first checkbox being checked

Answer (score 5):

You want a **[radio button](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/radio)**, (where only one option can be selected at a time)

```
<input name="option" type="radio" value="1" id="option1">option 1
<input name="option" type="radio" value="2" id="option2">option 2
```

---

Checkboxes can be grouped into arrays by appending [] to the end of their names:

```
<input name="option[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="option1">option 1
<input name="option[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="option2">option 2
```

This will **not** get the effect you want, it will instead group the checkboxes so that all input from them will result in one array. **it is still possible to select multiple checkboxes with this method**.

Comment: I never knew that checkboxes could be grouped into an array. Foolish of me to make assumptions!

Answer (score 1):

And retrieve the value of radio button as
**document.formName.radioboxName.value;**

Since you are giving same name for the radio buttons, only one value can be selected.

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery

```
var checked; 
$("input").each(function () {
   if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     checked[ $(this).attr("name")] = $(this).attr("value")
})
//checked is an array/object with all your checked checkboxs
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2826810/871050. OP didn't tag his question jQuery, he also isn't using jQuery on his example site. Why would you assume he wants to use jQuery?

Comment: I didn't say he can't, I said he probably **didn't want** there's a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Katherine if you want to select a single item from both the groups then you should go for the radio other wise you can not restrict to select only one check box and unnecessary you have to write a bulk of worth less code for that.

Also you have to mention the array of check boxes. the syntax you have taken is wrong the correct one is

```
<input name="option[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="option1">option 1
<input name="option[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="option2">option 2
```

and for radios

```
<input name="option" type="radio" value="1" id="option1">option 1
<input name="option" type="radio" value="2" id="option2">option 2
```

Answer (score 0):

**No jQuery Pure Javascript**

```
const checkedArr = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=myCheckboxGroup]:checked`)).map(node=>node.value);
```