# Apply CSS to element when there is only one occurrence?

Tags: css

Are there any CSS selectors (CSS3+ is fine) that will apply certain styles to an element when there is only a single occurrence?

For example, the following CSS rule:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

...would only apply to **.info** if there is only one occurrence of **.info** in the HTML.

So,

```
<p class="info">This would have a border because there is only one</p>
```

and,

```
<p class="info">This would not have a border because there are two</p>
<p class="info">And neither would this</p>
```

I'm guessing I'm going to have to either programatically apply an additional class such as: **.single-occurrence** or count the number of occurrences with Javascript?

Edit:

Let me just clear a few things up.

When I mention Javascript as a solution to what I'm trying to do - that does not mean I'm going to use it. I try to avoid JS for anything that is not behaviour. So I don't want a Javascript answer, that's incredibly easy to accomplish - my question is about CSS.

Also, to those getting confused: the reason why there would on occasion be only a **single** class on the page, is because the actual class I'm using is: **search-result**. Sometimes there would only be one result. But just because there's only one does not mean that the item cannot be part of the class of objects known as **search-result**. Semantically (and logically), of course there can be a class of one item. Sometimes, I think people should think a little more about semantics, instead of applying blanket rules.

Comment: I'm of the firm belief that there is no solution that meets the requirements of your question. CSS simply does not provide for this case, either in the spec or in practical implementation.

Comment: @michaelward82. Thanks, I suspected as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the structure of your page, you might be able to use the [`:only-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3aonly-of-type) pseudo-class, which matches if the element has no siblings of the same tag name.  I don't think there's a way to get more specific than that.

Comment: That seems to work. So now when there is only one search result I can style it like this:#search-results .search-result:only-of-type { border: 0; }

Answer (score 3):

If you want an answer in css, It will add the css only if it's the first and last element.

So if you want to apply this css only for one element it will work great for your problem but the answer need to be different if you only want to apply the css for two or three element for exemple.

```css
.info:first-of-type:is(:last-of-type) {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p class="info">This would have a border because there is only one</p>
```

---

```css
.info:first-of-type:is(:last-of-type) { 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p class="info">This would not have a border because there are two</p>
<p class="info">And neither would this</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS solution for this.  I'd go with your JavaScript idea.  If you were to use jQuery, you could use something like:

```
$('.info').length
```

List of CSS3 pseudo-classes here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses

Comment: Again... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826791/am-i-using-too-much-jquery-when-am-i-crossing-the-line/2826810#2826810

Comment: @Truth, while I appreciate your concern for the overuse of jQuery, am suggesting this solution as 1 option in case he's already using jQuery. Sure, there are [other of libraries](http://javascriptlibraries.com/) out there and he might be using, but I wasn't about to post an example for every one. Why use a library at all? Sure, create your own [`getElementsByClassName`](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/) function. But all of that is the OP's prerogative.

Answer (score -1):

How about this solution.

CSS

```
.info.highlight { border: 1px solid black }
```

JavaScript (using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com))

```
var $info = $('.info');
if ($info.length === 1) { $info.addClass('highlight'); }
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/YdbuB/

Comment: -1. OP stated he's looking for a CSS selector. He also mentioned he knows that if there isn't one he'll have to resort to JavaScript. Not only you put JavaScript on a [tag:css] question, you've put jQuery too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826791/am-i-using-too-much-jquery-when-am-i-crossing-the-line/2826810#2826810

Comment: My question is about CSS, not Javascript. Thanks though.

Answer (score -4):

hello it's a late answer with wrong syntax, but if u use selector like nth... with some very bad coding u could have your result