# PHP scan HTML for image tags and put in table

Tags: php

I'm not sure the best way to get a block of HTML containing img tags and text and be able to put these into separate table cells.

E.g

```
<img src="image.jpg> text
<img src="image2.jpg> text2
```

To

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="image.jpg></td> <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="image2.jpg></td> <td>text2</td>
</tr>
```

I think using preg_split is the right way but don't know where to start with the expression.
Also I would need somehow retain the chunk that the string is being split by.

Comment: The best way is to first get the data in some normalized format (e.g. an array of arrays) and then do the output IMHO.

Comment: @jrubins: [MOAR JQUERY](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2826810/871050). Also, OP tagged PHP.

Comment: @Truth this really does need moar jquery

Comment: Tagged PHP. Clearly OP wants PHP solution. OP really needs to provide more information though.

Comment: Maybe he isn't aware of jQuery? I don't think that's a ridiculous assumption.

Comment: FFS. If he's trying to do it client side (taking some image elements and reformatted into a table) then there is an even bigger problem: clearly the HTML is incorrectly formatted to begin with. Use jQuery for what it's meant for, not just for everything.

Comment: @Hamish the html isn't necessarily incorrectly formatted. Maybe he'd want to use this in response to some event. And you could say the same thing about PHP. If he's trying to do it server side then perhaps the HTML is incorrectly formatted to begin with.

Comment: @jrubins Except, that isn't stated in the question, and the question is tagged PHP. So, no.

Comment: I don't even use jQuery for javascript lol - no way am I using it for this, sorry.

Comment: @user1209203 can you please provide more background and some code you've tried so we can try to help you?

Comment: hakre that's the track I wanted to go on but I think I will need to use preg_split and have no idea how to write the expression properly

Comment: why dont you just use the src make an array and run a loop on the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use PHP, I recommend using a pre-made HTML dom parser. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net will work nicely. The site has tutorials for parsing out image tags.

Though you should definitely investigate using jQuery. It's probably better suited for this task.

Comment: OP want this made on the server side, not on the client side. There are another answer here which was deleted. jQuery is not a magical solution for everything. If OP wanted this client side, maybe **just maybe** I would consider using jQuery.