# Hiding a Check Box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have these two checkboxes:

```
<label for="cell">3. Do you currently have a cell phone? (Y/N)</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cell" name="cell" id="cell" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" />

<label for="blackBerry">4.If YES, is the cell phone a BlackBerry? (Y/N)</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="blackBerry" name="blackBerry" id= "blackBerry" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" />
```

How can I get the second question to display on the page, ONLY when the first one is selected as Yes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you meant the *first* one is selected as yes? Yes?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @lanzz - Something similar to this: http://forums.yessoftware.com/posts.php?post_id=119322, but it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using javascript

**Javascript**

```
​var elem = ​document.getElementById('cell');

​elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var divElem = document.getElementById('divPhone'); 
    if( this.checked){
        divElem.style.display = 'block'  ; 
    }
    else{
        divElem.style.display = 'none'  ;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
   <label for="cell">3. Do you currently have a cell phone? (Y/N)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cell" name="cell"
           id="cell" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" />

    <div id="divPhone" class="hidden">
      <label for="blackBerry">4.If YES, is the cell phone a BlackBerry?
                                                          (Y/N)</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="blackBerry" name="blackBerry" 
            id= "blackBerry" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" />
    </div>

​.hidden 
{
    display: none;
}​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/999y9/)**

​It is still more simple using jQuery..

```
​$('#cell').on('click', function() {
    if(this.checked){
       $('#divPhone').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else{
       $('#divPhone').addClass('hidden');
    }        
});​
```

**[jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/jcHUF/)**

Comment: The CSS only solution is still better, just for the record :)

Comment: @Meursault: You never said you wanted IE support.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - That's true. I forget people still use it. I see your point though, the CSS method is nice and simple.

Answer (score 3):

CSS only:

```
<label for="cell">3. Do you currently have a cell phone? (Y/N)</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cell" id="cell" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" />
<div class="hide_if_no">
    <label for="blackBerry">4. If YES, is the cell phone a BlackBerry? (Y/N)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="blackBerry" id="blackBerry" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] ~ div.hide_if_no {display:none}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.hide_if_no {display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery,

```
$('#cell').change(function() {
    var c = this.checked;
    if (c) {
        $("#blackBerry").show();
    } else {
        $("#blackBerry").hide();

    }
});​
```

Comment: I'd like to know why this was down-voted please so that I do not make the same error in posting answers again.

Comment: I think some people habitually downvote jQuery answers when the question didn't mention it.

Comment: @keithxm23: I am the downvoter, and I downvoted because of the MOAR JQUERY nature of this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2826810/871050. jQuery is useless here, this can be solved with JavaScript with easier and shorter code.

Comment: @Barmar: jQuery is an excellent framework for cross-browser complex DOM and event manipulation, with a great touch of effect. It is however, not needed for the purpose of this question, which consists of simple DOM manipulation, which can be done easily with JavaScript alone (And even CSS alone!)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Just because jQuery isn't the best solution doesn't mean it deserves a downvote. I generally reserve my downvotes for answers that fail to help at all (they either misunderstood the question or they contain misinformation). This discussion probably should be taking place on meta, not here.

Comment: @Barmar: let us continue this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php)