# How to remove strings by starting keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list of timezones and I need to display only the ones that starts with keyword America and remove the rest https://jsfiddle.net/o1yrcnrm/

```
<select class="form-select">
    <option value="Africa/Abidjan">Africa/Abidjan: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000
    </option>
    <option value="Africa/Accra">Africa/Accra: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000
    </option>
</select>
```

I assume this should work in the way that if starting keyword is not America then it gets deleted.

I'm currently looking at [Javascript how to remove text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398931/javascript-how-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

```
var ret = "data-123".replace('data-','');
console.log(ret);   //prints: 123
```

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Please be sure to include all relevant code in the question itself, not just on a third-party site. See [mcve]. It's not entirely clear what your end goal is. Do you want to remove any options that do not start with "America"? If so, then you likely don't want to just replace a string. You want to remove the elements themselves.

Comment: I think you have two choices : either have to delete the "option" element from the "select" if it matches your requirement or add a css class to make a css "display:none"

Comment: @floverdevel do you mean to call it somehow if option value="America" (not) then add CSS class?

Comment: Why do you render those options in your DOM if you don't want them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` only is going to modify the word and not to remove the whole item, try either with Regex or with `indexOf`, `includes`  methods.

```
var str = "America, ...";
var n = str.indexOf("America");
if(n !== -1){ //this means the 'America' is within the word }
```

here with how to achieve it with jQuery:

```js
$('.form-select option').each(function(i, item){
  if($(item).text().indexOf("America") !== 0){ 
    $(item).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-select">
  <option value="Africa/Abidjan">Africa/Abidjan: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
  <option value="Africa/Accra">Africa/Accra: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
  <option value="America/Argentina/Ushuaia">America/Argentina/Ushuaia: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
  <option value="America/Aruba">America/Aruba: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
  <option value="America/Asuncion">America/Asuncion: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
  <option value="America/Atikokan">America/Atikokan: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
  <option value="America/Bahia_Banderas">America/Bahia Banderas: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
  <option value="America/Bahia">America/Bahia: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
  <option value="America/Barbados">America/Barbados: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
  <option value="America/Belem">America/Belem: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
  <option value="America/Belize">America/Belize: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
  <option value="America/Blanc-Sablon">America/Blanc-Sablon: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
  <option value="America/Boa_Vista">America/Boa Vista: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
  <option value="Australia/Currie">Australia/Currie: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
  <option value="Australia/Darwin">Australia/Darwin: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 06:15 +0930</option>
  <option value="Australia/Eucla">Australia/Eucla: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 05:30 +0845</option>
  <option value="Australia/Hobart">Australia/Hobart: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
  <option value="Australia/Lindeman">Australia/Lindeman: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 06:45 +1000</option>
  <option value="Australia/Lord_Howe">Australia/Lord Howe: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
  <option value="Australia/Melbourne">Australia/Melbourne: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
</select>
```

further information: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Comment: @user3108268 as you tag your question with jQuery, I assume that you are using it, in my answer you can see how to do it with jQuery

Comment: Had to repick yours as an answer because since I'm running this on Drupal, the raw javascript solution is not working, but jQuery does.

Answer (score 3):

You just need **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** to get the index position of the string "America" within the entire `value`. If it is not `0`, then the `value` doesn't start with "America" and you should remove the node.

JQuery is overkill **[for something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826791/am-i-using-too-much-jquery-when-am-i-crossing-the-line)**. When it first came out, the DOM API wasn't as mature as it is now and JQuery made just about everything easy. Now that JavaScript and the DOM API have evolved, much of what JQuery can do for us, can now be accomplished just as easily with vanilla JavaScript. JQuery still has its place, but for more advanced operations than simple queries, string operations and DOM searches.

```js
// Get all the <option> elements into an array
var values = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("option"));

// Loop over the array
values.forEach(function(opt){
  if(opt.value.indexOf("America") !== 0){  // If the value doesn't start with "America"
    opt.parentNode.removeChild(opt);   // Remove the <option> from the document
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="edit-timezone--2" name="timezone" class="form-select">
    <option value="Africa/Abidjan">Africa/Abidjan: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Africa/Accra">Africa/Accra: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa">Africa/Addis Ababa: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Africa/Freetown">Africa/Freetown: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Africa/Gaborone">Africa/Gaborone: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Harare">Africa/Harare: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Johannesburg">Africa/Johannesburg: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Juba">Africa/Juba: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Africa/Kampala">Africa/Kampala: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Africa/Khartoum">Africa/Khartoum: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Kigali">Africa/Kigali: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Kinshasa">Africa/Kinshasa: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Africa/Lagos">Africa/Lagos: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Africa/Libreville">Africa/Libreville: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Africa/Lome">Africa/Lome: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Africa/Luanda">Africa/Luanda: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Africa/Lubumbashi">Africa/Lubumbashi: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Lusaka">Africa/Lusaka: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Malabo">Africa/Malabo: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Africa/Maputo">Africa/Maputo: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Maseru">Africa/Maseru: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Mbabane">Africa/Mbabane: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Africa/Mogadishu">Africa/Mogadishu: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Africa/Monrovia">Africa/Monrovia: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Africa/Nairobi">Africa/Nairobi: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="America/Barbados">America/Barbados: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Belem">America/Belem: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Belize">America/Belize: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Blanc-Sablon">America/Blanc-Sablon: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Boa_Vista">America/Boa Vista: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Bogota">America/Bogota: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Boise">America/Boise: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Cambridge_Bay">America/Cambridge Bay: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Campo_Grande">America/Campo Grande: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Cancun">America/Cancun: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Caracas">America/Caracas: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Cayenne">America/Cayenne: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Cayman">America/Cayman: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Chicago">America/Chicago: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Chihuahua">America/Chihuahua: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Costa_Rica">America/Costa Rica: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Creston">America/Creston: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Cuiaba">America/Cuiaba: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Curacao">America/Curacao: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Danmarkshavn">America/Danmarkshavn: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="America/Dawson_Creek">America/Dawson Creek: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Dawson">America/Dawson: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 12:45 -0800</option>
    <option value="America/Denver">America/Denver: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Detroit">America/Detroit: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Dominica">America/Dominica: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Edmonton">America/Edmonton: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Eirunepe">America/Eirunepe: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/El_Salvador">America/El Salvador: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Fort_Nelson">America/Fort Nelson: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Fortaleza">America/Fortaleza: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Glace_Bay">America/Glace Bay: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Godthab">America/Godthab: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Goose_Bay">America/Goose Bay: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Grand_Turk">America/Grand Turk: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Grenada">America/Grenada: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Guadeloupe">America/Guadeloupe: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Guatemala">America/Guatemala: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Guayaquil">America/Guayaquil: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Guyana">America/Guyana: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Halifax">America/Halifax: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Havana">America/Havana: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Hermosillo">America/Hermosillo: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Indiana/Indianapolis">America/Indiana/Indianapolis: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Indiana/Knox">America/Indiana/Knox: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Indiana/Marengo">America/Indiana/Marengo: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Indiana/Petersburg">America/Indiana/Petersburg: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Indiana/Tell_City">America/Indiana/Tell City: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Indiana/Vevay">America/Indiana/Vevay: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Indiana/Vincennes">America/Indiana/Vincennes: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Indiana/Winamac">America/Indiana/Winamac: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Inuvik">America/Inuvik: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 13:45 -0700</option>
    <option value="America/Iqaluit">America/Iqaluit: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Jamaica">America/Jamaica: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Juneau">America/Juneau: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 11:45 -0900</option>
    <option value="America/Kentucky/Louisville">America/Kentucky/Louisville: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Kentucky/Monticello">America/Kentucky/Monticello: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Kralendijk">America/Kralendijk: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/La_Paz">America/La Paz: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Nassau">America/Nassau: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/New_York">America/New York: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Nipigon">America/Nipigon: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Nome">America/Nome: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 11:45 -0900</option>
    <option value="America/Noronha">America/Noronha: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 18:45 -0200</option>
    <option value="America/Punta_Arenas">America/Punta Arenas: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Rainy_River">America/Rainy River: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Rankin_Inlet">America/Rankin Inlet: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Recife">America/Recife: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Regina">America/Regina: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Resolute">America/Resolute: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Rio_Branco">America/Rio Branco: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 15:45 -0500</option>
    <option value="America/Santarem">America/Santarem: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Santiago">America/Santiago: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:45 -0300</option>
    <option value="America/Santo_Domingo">America/Santo Domingo: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Sao_Paulo">America/Sao Paulo: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 18:45 -0200</option>
    <option value="America/Scoresbysund">America/Scoresbysund: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 19:45 -0100</option>
    <option value="America/Sitka">America/Sitka: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 11:45 -0900</option>
    <option value="America/St_Barthelemy">America/St Barthelemy: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/St_Johns">America/St Johns: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 17:15 -0330</option>
    <option value="America/St_Kitts">America/St Kitts: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/St_Lucia">America/St Lucia: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/St_Thomas">America/St Thomas: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/St_Vincent">America/St Vincent: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="America/Swift_Current">America/Swift Current: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Tegucigalpa">America/Tegucigalpa: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 14:45 -0600</option>
    <option value="America/Thule">America/Thule: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 16:45 -0400</option>
    <option value="Antarctica/Vostok">Antarctica/Vostok: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 02:45 +0600</option>
    <option value="Arctic/Longyearbyen">Arctic/Longyearbyen: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Asia/Aden">Asia/Aden: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Asia/Almaty">Asia/Almaty: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 02:45 +0600</option>
    <option value="Asia/Amman">Asia/Amman: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Asia/Anadyr">Asia/Anadyr: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 08:45 +1200</option>
    <option value="Asia/Irkutsk">Asia/Irkutsk: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 04:45 +0800</option>
    <option value="Asia/Jakarta">Asia/Jakarta: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 03:45 +0700</option>
    <option value="Asia/Jayapura">Asia/Jayapura: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 05:45 +0900</option>
    <option value="Asia/Jerusalem">Asia/Jerusalem: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Asia/Kabul">Asia/Kabul: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 01:15 +0430</option>
    <option value="Asia/Kamchatka">Asia/Kamchatka: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 08:45 +1200</option>
    <option value="Asia/Karachi">Asia/Karachi: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 01:45 +0500</option>
    <option value="Asia/Kathmandu">Asia/Kathmandu: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 02:30 +0545</option>
    <option value="Asia/Khandyga">Asia/Khandyga: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 05:45 +0900</option>
    <option value="Asia/Sakhalin">Asia/Sakhalin: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
    <option value="Asia/Samarkand">Asia/Samarkand: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 01:45 +0500</option>
    <option value="Asia/Seoul">Asia/Seoul: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 05:45 +0900</option>
    <option value="Asia/Shanghai">Asia/Shanghai: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 04:45 +0800</option>
    <option value="Asia/Singapore">Asia/Singapore: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 04:45 +0800</option>
    <option value="Asia/Srednekolymsk">Asia/Srednekolymsk: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
    <option value="Asia/Taipei">Asia/Taipei: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 04:45 +0800</option>
    <option value="Asia/Tashkent">Asia/Tashkent: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 01:45 +0500</option>
    <option value="Asia/Tbilisi">Asia/Tbilisi: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 00:45 +0400</option>
    <option value="Asia/Tehran">Asia/Tehran: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 00:15 +0330</option>
    <option value="Asia/Thimphu">Asia/Thimphu: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 02:45 +0600</option>
    <option value="Asia/Tokyo">Asia/Tokyo: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 05:45 +0900</option>
    <option value="Asia/Tomsk">Asia/Tomsk: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 03:45 +0700</option>
    <option value="Australia/Eucla">Australia/Eucla: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 05:30 +0845</option>
    <option value="Australia/Hobart">Australia/Hobart: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
    <option value="Australia/Lindeman">Australia/Lindeman: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 06:45 +1000</option>
    <option value="Australia/Lord_Howe">Australia/Lord Howe: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
    <option value="Australia/Melbourne">Australia/Melbourne: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
    <option value="Australia/Perth">Australia/Perth: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 04:45 +0800</option>
    <option value="Australia/Sydney">Australia/Sydney: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Chisinau">Europe/Chisinau: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Europe/Copenhagen">Europe/Copenhagen: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Dublin">Europe/Dublin: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Europe/Gibraltar">Europe/Gibraltar: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Guernsey">Europe/Guernsey: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Europe/Helsinki">Europe/Helsinki: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Europe/Isle_of_Man">Europe/Isle of Man: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Europe/Istanbul">Europe/Istanbul: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Europe/Jersey">Europe/Jersey: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Europe/Kaliningrad">Europe/Kaliningrad: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Europe/Kiev">Europe/Kiev: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Europe/Kirov">Europe/Kirov: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Europe/Lisbon">Europe/Lisbon: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
    <option value="Europe/Ljubljana">Europe/Ljubljana: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Tirane">Europe/Tirane: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Ulyanovsk">Europe/Ulyanovsk: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 00:45 +0400</option>
    <option value="Europe/Uzhgorod">Europe/Uzhgorod: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Europe/Vaduz">Europe/Vaduz: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Vatican">Europe/Vatican: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Vienna">Europe/Vienna: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Vilnius">Europe/Vilnius: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Europe/Volgograd">Europe/Volgograd: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Europe/Warsaw">Europe/Warsaw: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Zagreb">Europe/Zagreb: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Europe/Zaporozhye">Europe/Zaporozhye: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 22:45 +0200</option>
    <option value="Europe/Zurich">Europe/Zurich: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 21:45 +0100</option>
    <option value="Indian/Antananarivo">Indian/Antananarivo: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Indian/Chagos">Indian/Chagos: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 02:45 +0600</option>
    <option value="Indian/Christmas">Indian/Christmas: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 03:45 +0700</option>
    <option value="Indian/Cocos">Indian/Cocos: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 03:15 +0630</option>
    <option value="Indian/Comoro">Indian/Comoro: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Indian/Kerguelen">Indian/Kerguelen: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 01:45 +0500</option>
    <option value="Indian/Mahe">Indian/Mahe: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 00:45 +0400</option>
    <option value="Indian/Maldives">Indian/Maldives: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 01:45 +0500</option>
    <option value="Indian/Mauritius">Indian/Mauritius: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 00:45 +0400</option>
    <option value="Indian/Mayotte">Indian/Mayotte: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 23:45 +0300</option>
    <option value="Indian/Reunion">Indian/Reunion: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 00:45 +0400</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Apia">Pacific/Apia: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 10:45 +1400</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Auckland">Pacific/Auckland: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 09:45 +1300</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Bougainville">Pacific/Bougainville: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 07:45 +1100</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Chatham">Pacific/Chatham: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 10:30 +1345</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Chuuk">Pacific/Chuuk: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 06:45 +1000</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Saipan">Pacific/Saipan: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 06:45 +1000</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Tahiti">Pacific/Tahiti: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 10:45 -1000</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Tarawa">Pacific/Tarawa: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 08:45 +1200</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Tongatapu">Pacific/Tongatapu: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 09:45 +1300</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Wake">Pacific/Wake: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 08:45 +1200</option>
    <option value="Pacific/Wallis">Pacific/Wallis: Friday, February 9, 2018 - 08:45 +1200</option>
    <option value="UTC">UTC: Thursday, February 8, 2018 - 20:45 +0000</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: That `results` variable is not used :p

Comment: @ChinLeung Yes, I just took it out.

Comment: Why do you say the HTML is not valid?

Comment: @floverdevel My mistake. It must be that there was just so much of it, that the parser needed time to parse it.